# Check if one method has been run in a different method

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm writing some code in Xcode for an iPhone app and I want to be able to detect if a method has been run (i.e. a button was pressed, causing that method to run) in another method (I want to use an if statement so that if the button was pressed it will do this, but if it wasn't then it will do something else).

Comment: A counting semaphore? What kind of reset logic? A simple `BOOL` could do it.

Comment: I'm a little confused by your question, but why not just add a `BOOL` property named something like "xMethodIsRunning" and at the beginning of your button method set that to `YES`, and at the end set it to `NO`? Then just check that in your other method. But perhaps I misunderstanding what you want.

Comment: You could always set the tag of the button to different values, based on what the first method did.

Answer (score 2):

There is no has_method_been_run() function but you can check to see if the state was changed.

For example say method button_clicked() calls method change_font_to_blue(). In this case you can check to see if the font is blue and there for the method was called.

That's a very basic example of course but you could check any number of variables / the state of the UI to see if it was changed.

OR you can add a boolean to an object and just set it to true when you execute you're method that you're watching.

Answer (score 0):

If your example is simply a button press I would change the UIButton's selected state

```
- (IBAction)buttonSelected:(UIButton *)sender {
    sender.selected = YES;
    // OR:
    // self.myButton.selected = YES;
}

- (void)otherMethod {
    if (self.myButton.isSelected) {
        // button has been run through the selector method

        // if you want, reset button's selected state
        self.myButton.selected = NO;
    } else {
        // button has NOT been run through the selector method
    }
}
```

This is a simple idea and by default the selected state of a UIButton is not visually different. If you want it to be visually changed then you can simply go into IB and change the visuals there for the selected state (including the title):

[image: Button visual options in IB]

Then when the button is set to selected (`self.myButton.selected = YES;`) it will automatically change what the button looks like!